# docker-compose to access port on host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Ip of host machine is `192.168.0.208`.

`docker-compose` file is as follows:

```
version: '2'
 services:
   zl-tigervnc:
     image: zl/dl-tigervnc:1.5
     container_name: zl_dl_tigervnc
     restart: always
     tty: true
     ports:
       - "8001:8888"
       - "6001:6006"
       - "8901:5900"
       - "10001:22"
     devices:
       - /dev/nvidia0
     volumes:
       - ~/data:/root/data
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
     extra_hosts:
       - "dockerhost:192.168.0.208"
```

A container was launched by this script. The container want to access port `8080` on the host machine (e.g. `192.168.0.208:8080`). But it doesn't  work.

However, I use port forwarding to map `8080` on host machine to `8080` on router. Router's IP was `63.25.20.83`. The container could access host machine's `8080` by port forwarding(e.g. `63.25.20.83:8080`).

I have tried many solutions from https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143, but it still does not work.

Comment: Can you ping your host within the container? With the container running, execute `docker exec your-container-name ping -c 3 192.168.0.208`

Comment: `PING 192.168.0.208 (192.168.0.208) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.208: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.208: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.208: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms`

Comment: command `ping` worked.

Comment: Ok, so it does not look like a conectivity problem. Are you referencing the host by name, `dockerhost`? Maybe your software is bypassing the `/etc/hosts` file to resolve names. Try to connect directly to 192.168.0.208:8080 using `telnet`or `curl`.

Comment: Thanks. `ufw disable` solved my problem. It's the problem from firewall of the host